# Are URLs in alt text usable?

Tags: accessibility, html, urls, screen-reader

In [a recent edit I made on UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/50260), I added some [`alt` text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute) to an image that contained the URL of a page at which the reader could see a textual version of the content in the image.

However, I'm unsure whether including links in `alt` text like this is actually useful. How will a screen reader handle such a URL? Does software typically used by blind or vision-impaired users provide a means to visit such URLs - for instance, by enabling them to copy the `alt` text to the clipboard? Or is such a link effectively impossible to follow for the audience at which it is aimed?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [longdesc](http://accessibility.psu.edu/images/imageshtml/#extended) attribute that is supposed to be supported by screenreaders and it serves exactly the purpose.

Comment: Hmm. `longdesc` is interesting and relevant, but this doesn't directly answer the question (and there seems to be at least one good reason not to use it: namely, that it has incomplete support (according to your source).

Comment: Well, obviously `alt` is not the way to go. [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-longdesc) also describes it as a 'link to description' placeholder.

Comment: With a bit more research, `longdesc` is supported by [NVDA and JAWS](https://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/longdesctestcases.htm) which adds up to [almost 80% of the screen reader users](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey7/)

Comment: *"Well, obviously alt is not the way to go"* - uh, why? This is entirely non-obvious to me, or else I wouldn't've asked the question. Besides the fact that `longdesc` isn't supported everywhere, how else do the behaviours of `alt` and `longdesc` differ?

Comment: *"longdesc is supported by NVDA and JAWS"* - your own linked source paints a somewhat more nuanced picture than that. Yes, NVDA and JAWS support `longdesc`... when working with IE or Firefox, but *not* with Chrome.

Comment: Well, `alt` is not meant to hold a link, but `longdesc` is. You're free to do more research about it though.

Answer (score 1):

The `alt` attribute is for plain text. So it can’t contain hyperlinks, but it can contain URLs.

Custom implementations aside, a screen reader wouldn’t offer to visit the URL, but it would read it out. Depending on the screen reader, the user might have to switch to a different mode to also hear the punctuation (the parts "https" and "www" should suffice as indicators for recognizing that it’s a URL).

So at that point, it’s like a radio advertisement which contains a URL. Interested people can remember it (or note it down), and enter it manually.

#### But *should* the `alt` attribute contain URLs?

Only in one case: if the image shows URLs.

Relevant guidelines (from HTML’s [Requirements for providing text to act as an alternative for images](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/semantics-embedded-content.html#alt-text)):

- [Images of text](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/semantics-embedded-content.html#images-of-text)
- [Images that include text](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/semantics-embedded-content.html#images-that-include-text)

However, in such a case it might be better to use an [alternative to `img`+`alt`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/91692/17633), which allows using a hyperlink (`a`).

In your example, the `alt` attribute should not contain the URL, as it’s not part of the image. The URL might also be interesting for users that don’t read the `alt` text (as it allows copy-pasting, might contain updates, gives more information about the author, and so on), so the best solution would be to link it next to the image (which the answer already does).